# Sending PHP Strings Variables to a Javascript String Variables

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I am trying to send a long string of numbers from a file to Javascript. One I get it in Javascript as a string the rest will be easy.

This is the PHP code that grabs the series of numbers. It does grab them properly because it prints it out perfectly if I instruct it to do so.

```
$data = readfile($dataFile);
```

This is the Javascript Code:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
```

When ever I run it the variable "data" is set to a random number. I assume it is the the number of characters in the sequence. I am relatively new to PHP and Javascript so a nice and clear explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does console.log(data) gives you?

Comment: JSON is a string, so I suspect no quotes around the PHP output is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number that is set in the variable `$data` is the number of bytes read by `readfile`. This is because `readfile` only reads the file and outputs its content to the standard output. To get the actual data in the file and assign it to a viariable, you can use `file_get_contents()`, like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents($dataFile);
```

Then the javascript assignment is good ;)

Answer (score 3):

Readfile reads the contents of the file and outputs them. It returns the byte length of the file, so $data is the number of the read bytes. [link](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.readfile.php).

Comment: +1 It would be great if you could show a solution using `file_get_contents` instead.

Comment: You want the js-variable data to have the content of the file?

Comment: I believe that is what the OP is expecting

Comment: Ok, than he has to replace readfile($dataFile) with file_get_contents($dataFile)

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes if you want it to be a string in Javascript:

```
var data = '<?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;';
```

Comment: No, you should not add quotes since `json_encode` adds them automatically if the variable `$data` is a string. Also, if you add quotes you will have problems if the `$data` variable contains a string that includes quotes.

Comment: @ClaudioVenturini It doesn't add the quotes with `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`. Try it: `echo json_encode('123', JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` will output `123`, not `'123'`.

Comment: Ok, but that it's fine because `123` it's a number, and so it's perfectly valid to assign it to a javascript variable without quotes. If you do `json_encode('a_string')`, you get `"a_string"` and not `a_string`

Comment: @ClaudioVenturini It's valid Javascript to do `var data = 123;`, but then `typeof data` will be `'number'`, and the OP specifically asked for a string in Javascript. I would say that an answer combining our two answers gives the OP exactly what they want.